# How to save this type of object in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vev5.png)Please tell me how to make schema and save API for the following object in MongoDB

Need to save 'btcinr' because this data will come from an API..
 `{ "btcinr": { "base_unit": "btc", "quote_unit": "inr", "low": "2712288.0", "high": "2840292.0", "last": "2738934.0", "type": "SPOT", "open": "2836081", "volume": "85.17037", "sell": "2743398.0", "buy": "2740052.0", "at": 1652080075, "name": "BTC/INR" }, }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make such a schema in mongoose. Example:

```js
const crypto = new mongoose.Schema({ base_unit: String, quote_unit: String, etc... });
```

and if you 'model' the schema like so:

```js
const Crypto = mongoose.model('Crypto', crypto);
```

you can easily store it in your database by:

```js
Crypto.create({ base_unit: "btc", etc... });
```

You can find more on that here: https://mongoosejs.com/

Edit: The answer stays the same, just put an object where you need it to be an object along with it's properties, besides that, there is always the [LINK](https://mongoosejs.com/). That's all I have to say here, I feel like I shouldn't be giving answers 'on plate'.